# find map by providing country,city and street

Tags: android

in my application findlocation opptions is there.can u please help me how to find out the corresponding map by providing the country,city,street or pincode. please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object, you can use the method `getFromLocationName` that accepts an address and the number of result (if several locations are found)

It returns a list of [Address](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects that contain methods `getLongitude()` and `getLatitude()`

Having the latitude and longitude, you can make a GeoPoint and use it for your mapController

Comment: what u said it is right i am also did like what u said when i call getFromLocationName only first time it is throwing exception again if i call same method it is returning that lat and lon what is the problem for first time why it is throwing error

Comment: What error is it? Take a look at LogCat for useful information for debugging.